# how to KVC for self.typeOfAssetLabel.text

Tags: ios, objective-c, kvc

I have some `UILabels` connected to `UIOutlet` properties. I would like to set the text property for the labels by KVC, because I have the label-property-names as string.

So, usually (no KVC) I would access them like so:

```
self.typeOfAssetLabel.text = @"Hello";
```

Now, what would that be in KVC?

I tried:

```
[self.typeOfAssetLabel setValue:@"test" forKey:@"text"];
```

and this works. But this way I can't set the property name `typeOfAssetLabel` by string.

I would guess this should work

```
[self setValue:@"test" forKey:@"typeOfAssetLabel.text"];
```

but this way I get the "is not key-value complient..." error. What would be the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is:

```
[self setValue: @"test" forKeyPath: @"typeOfAssetLabel.text"];
```

The trick is using `forKeyPath` instead of `forKey` when there's more than one key in the path.